# How to change ledmac's paragraph footnotes from justified to ragged

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, paragraphs, ledmac

How to change `ledmac`'s paragraph footnotes from justified to ragged ? They seem to be justified by default, but I need them ragged **left**. Probably needs a redefinition of `\parafootfmt`, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit: the solutions provided works for ragged right but not ragged left...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\TeXXeTstate=1

\usepackage{ledmac}

\footparagraphX{A}

\begin{document}

hello

\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello  hello hello }

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW just as information: Take a look on the successor package `eledmac`.

Comment: @Speravir Here is an example ; I just looked at eledmac, it doesn't seem to be included in my distribution, I'll try to install it.

Comment: What about the main text?  Is that RTL as well?  What language(s) are involved?  What side does the footnote marker go on? And are you aware of the `ledarab` package (which I've never really used)?

Comment: @jon The main text is in Hebrew (RTL), footnote marker and footnotes are LTR english. I'll check the package you mention today !

Answer (score 4):

With `eledmac` it is very easy: It provides a command `\notenumfontX` for font switching in familiar footnotes, as they are called in `eledmac` – in the example below I intentionally added `\itshape`.

<sup>For critical footnotes there is `\Xnotenumfont`.</sup>

Note, that I had to use the package `ragged2e` and its command `\RaggedRight` as also shown in Jon’s answer. With the kernel command `\raggedright` nothing happens, Try it out: I added a commented line. The package `babel` is added, because it improves in many cases the hyphenation significantly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{eledmac}
  \footparagraphX{A}
%  \notenumfontX[A]{\raggedright}
  \notenumfontX[A]{\RaggedRight\itshape}

\begin{document}
Hello%
\footnoteA{% text taken from package "blindtext"
  Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This text should show what a
  printed text will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will get
  no information. Really? Is there no information? Is there a difference between
  this text and some nonsense like ``Huardest gefburn''? Kjift -- not at all! A
  blind text \emph{like this} gives you information about the selected font, how
  the letters are written and an impression of the look. This text should
  contain \emph{all letters of the alphabet} and it should be written in of the
  original language. There is no need for special contents, but the length of
  words should match the language.%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of footnote]

Comment: I can't download the eledmac package from CTAN, the connection is reset each time I try to download the file. I'll look at it as soon as I can get it. For now, I'll use Jon's answer with the "old" ledmac.

Comment: You should get this with the package manager of your recent TeX distribution. Also you could try another CTAN mirror.

Comment: @jon I just tried both solutions on my document. Since it is in a right-to-left language, I would need the paragraph notes to be ragged left, but in both the ledmac and eledmac solutions, the `\RaggedLeft` or `\raggedleft` commands produce a ragged right paragraph ... (I also tried with the english  example you provided, just replacing '\RaggedRight' with '\RaggedLeft', with the same result)

Comment: @Tonton80 First: This is all essential information you had to give from the beginning, also an minimal example with rtl text. Second: What happens with `\RaggedRight`? Try out, please.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would change anything, so I gave the most simple example. I tried both commands, `\RaggedRight` works and gives a ragged right paragraph, but the problem is that `\RaggedLeft` also gives a ragged right paragraph ...

Comment: I am sorry, too, then, because I cannot help in this case. RTL support is unfortunately general not that good in a lot packages.

Comment: @Tonton80 I cannot say anything about it, but do you know the `bidi`package?

Comment: Yes, but all the `bidi` commands are ignored when used in the present case.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: I don't have the old version of `ledmac` on this computer, but this should still work.)

You can add a 'ragged right' command to `\ledsetnormalparstuff`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\TeXXeTstate=1

\usepackage[noeledmac]{ledmac}% option needed for newer versions of ledmac (now deprecated in favour of eledmac)
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ledsetnormalparstuff}{%
  \RaggedRight% <-- added; from ragged2e.sty; better than plain \raggedright
  \normal@pars
  \parindent \z@ \parfillskip \z@ \@plus 1fil}
\makeatother 

\footparagraphX{A}

\begin{document}
hello%
\footnoteA{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 
  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 
  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
  hello hello hello hello hello hello }  
\end{document}
```